# Google Sheets: How to count cells in range that contain a formula (not literal)

Tags: google-sheets, range

In google sheets I'm trying to see whether there are any formulas in a range of cells (a count of cells with formulas would be nice, though not necessary).

In column A:

```
Foo
2
=1+2
```

I've tried:

```
=ISFORMULA(A1:A3)
=OR(ISFORMULA(A1:A3))
=ARRAYFORMULA(ISFORMULA(A1:A3))
```

and they all return FALSE

I expected to get TRUE.
It appears that it only tests the first cell in the range.

What other options are there using a range in a formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MAP to check all cells. If it's a formula, you can set the value to 1, and then sum the values:

```
=SUM(MAP(A1:C, LAMBDA(each,IF(ISFORMULA(each),1,0))))
```

Comment: Brilliant!!! ...and elegant! Thank you! I changed the range to "A1:A3" and it works perfectly. I've been scouring the interwebs and there has not been a solution yet.  ...now all I need to do is to understand it ;-)

Comment: Haha, I'm glad it was useful! MAP lets you iterate a "process" over a range, cell by cell, creating a "new resulting range". LAMBDA the only thing that it does is allow you to name that "cell" each time (you can name it "each" or you can name it "cell" or whatever you want). And finally the actual formula stablish that if it's a formula, the cell will be considered as 1, and if it isn't, as a 0. The resulting range is a group of 1s and 0s, that just needs to be summed ;)